# Factoring out embedded ruby code in a view (MVC)

Tags: html, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, embedded-ruby

I am doing Michael Hartl's railstutorial.org and I am trying to do an exercise factoring out a form in a view. Here is the link to the chapter, and the problem is associated with listing 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7. I am trying to figure out exactly how to provide the proper `:url`, at least that's what I think I'm doing.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

Here is my code:
_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => yield(:url) do |f| %>  
     ...  
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit user') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
<% provide(:url, edit_user_path(current_user)) %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<% provide(:url, new_user_path) %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried repeatedly to get this to work, trying various ways, but so far, to no avail. Here is the test that is failing:

```
 FAIL["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2.447965808212757]
 test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (2.45s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "form[action="/signup"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

and the code for it:

```
  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "form[action=\"/signup\"]"
```

routes.rb

```
  get     '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post    '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  patch   '/signup',  to: 'users#update'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is `new_user_path` routed to `/signup` ? Probably not as I would assume it would be something like `post '/signup', to: 'users#create', as: :signup_path` and you would use sign up path. Also for edit this should probably be `user_path(@user.id)` but without seeing your routes I can not be sure.

Comment: So I changed it to signup_path and I also changed it to user_path(@user.id) and it worked! Thank you!